# How to make AS3 wait for a JSON.parse to complete?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I’m writing a class that checks for a message (in the form of a JSON array) on a server,
then checks to see if that particular message has already been stored locally.

I want to parse the server message, then call a function that checks the local message and compares values between the two (e.g. message numbers).

But there’s no COMPLETE event for the JSON class, and I’m not sure how to slow my code down enough so that it waits for the first parse before parsing the local file (which is also a JSON array).

I’m worried that, somehow, the second parse could finish before the first and then try to compare a real value against a null object.

This isn’t actually happening at the moment, because the 2nd parse takes as long as the first. But is there a way to make it more of sure thing, in any event?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that `JSON.parse()` is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that I've ever understood what that means. I've noticed that a simple 'trace()' put into my 2nd function will execute before the parse is complete in the first function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` is a synchronous task, meaning it will complete before your application continues, e.g.

```
var a:Object = JSON.parse('{}'); // Will always complete before;
var b:Object = JSON.parse('{}');
```

I assume what you actually mean is you want to be absolutely certain that the data from the server is available before you make your check, which is as easy as doing that check within the `COMPLETE` handler of the `URLLoader` object you use to retrieve the JSON.

Comment: That helps. Currently I retrieve the JSON from server, parse it after the load is complete, call the 2nd function that retrieves the local JSON, parse IT after it's load is complete, and THEN compare values. Are you saying that I never have to worry about this? I'm only asking because of what I noticed in my comment, above.